# CONVERT lat and long field in PostgreSQL using ST_GeomFromText

Tags: postgresql

i have two fields for lat and long in point text record.how can i use ST_GeomFromText function for all of my records to convert it into geometry?? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a geometry column:

```
alter table my_table add geom geometry(point, 4326);
```

Then populated it with geometry built from ST_MakePoint and setting the SRID:

```
UPDATE my_table set geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint("GEO_LON", "GEO_LAT"), 4326);
```

(Note you'll set your LON/LAT columns according to your data)

4326 is the WGS84 coordinate system, which it looks like your data is in.

Comment: Please accept the answer then.